# Why does this xor operation result in zero in mysql?

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

Why does this xor operation zero out?

```
mysql> select 17246357237183571361 xor 13175113390712773921;

+-----------------------------------------------+
| 17246357237183571361 xor 13175113390712773921 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Does adding quotes around the operands help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not a bitwise operation it is a logical operation. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

So it boils down to 1 xor 1

Comment: In other words, it's no different than `'a' xor 'b' -> 0`

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Captain Giraffe is correct but probably it's useful to know that you can write the following to have MySQL executing a bitwise XOR on the operands:

```
mysql> select 17246357237183571361 ^ 13175113390712773921;
```

The result would be 6449217728581286016.

I needed this to determine the hamming distance of 2 perceptual hashes (similar image search) which is easily done by this line

```
BIT_COUNT(pHash1 ^ pHash2)
```

Perhaps other users can profit from :-)